# lstlisting messes up page numbers in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I don't get page numbers of sections in the table of content correctly when I use the package `lstlisting`. I'm using the documentclass `article`. I need to use this class, not `report`.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: Did you run `latex` a few times?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I make sure I'm not overrunning Latex. I close everything then try.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38802/long-table-of-contents-makes-page-numbers-wrong

Comment: In order to get the correct page numbers, a couple of LaTeX runs are needed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752869/latex-lstlisting-messes-up-page-numbers-in-table-of-content?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Information contained within the Table of Contents is extracted from a file that is created after you run `latex`. As such, it usually takes (at least) two separate runs in order for the entries to be there and correct. If this is not the case, edit your post and include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments I suspect that you are not running latex enough times.  Compiling the example below the first time produces:

[image]

But upon subsequent run (assuming that you do not delete the temporary files that are generated upon the first run) you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.java}
 public int nextInt(int n) {
     if (n<=0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

     if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
         return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

     int bits, val;
     do {
         bits = next(31);
         val = bits % n;
     } while(bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
     return val;
 }
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\newpage
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1-7]

\lstinputlisting{foo.java}

\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[8-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I use Latexian for Mac. I figured that it runs 2 times by default. I changed it to 3 times, and that took care of the issue.